# Create Dashboard to track Target Activities

Tags: reporting, dashboard, activities, analytics

I would like to create a report with a Dashboard component that compares the number of activities that a user has logged in a Current Quarter against a Target number of activities that have been set for them that quarter.

We currently do not have a method of tracking 'Target Activities' so I am open to suggestions! Any ideas?

Comment: Can you set up this target per user or per column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [formula](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_builder_fields_formulas.htm&language=en_US) in the report to set a Target value, then plot the Target as an additional value in the graph.

[image: Graph with Target line]